# Не компилирует Qt под Android?

Tags: android, qt, android-sdk

Не компилирует Qt под Android. Как решить проблему?

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\Android\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:888: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Android\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:890: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Android\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:902: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Android\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:283: null returned: 1
```